# how to merge data in python

Tags: python, merge

I just learn python for not long. And I had try my best to represent my data looks better just like showing before.
Now I have some tuple data type which look like this:

```
('John', '5', 'Coke')
('Mary', '1', 'Pie')
('Jack', '3', 'Milk')
('Mary', '2', 'Water') 
('John', '3', 'Coke')
```

And I wanna count how many items that each one had bought.

Assume that the different name is different person.

So how could I do in order to get some information like this below:

```
 John: 8 Coke 
 Mary: 1 Pie 
 Mary: 2 Water 
 Jack: 3 Milk
```

I have no idea how could I do now. I can't come up with any method even the stupid one.

Comment: That `tuples` are a tuple of tuples? Or there are different tuples?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd suggest using name and drink as a key for [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
count = Counter()
for name, amount, drink in tuples:
    key = name, drink
    count.update({key: int(amount)})  # increment the value

# represent the aggregated data
for (name, drink), amount in count.items():
    print('{}: {} {}'.format(name, amount, drink))
```

**Update** I made some simple measurements, and figured out that

```
count[name, drink] += value
```

is not only more readable, but much faster than calling `update`, which should not be a surprise. Moreover, `defaultdict(int)` is even faster (about twice) than that (presumably, because `Counter` performs some ordering additionally.)

Comment: is `tuples` a list of tuples? If it's, this doesnt work (2.7))

Comment: `count.update({key: amount})` -> `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`. You are using the numbers as int, and the OP's are strings.

Comment: @Borja I see, that's because `amount` is string in the input. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: Thanks guys. It works and it's really helpful for me. :)

Comment: @WenT I slightly improved the answer, `count[name, drink] += value` is more readable.

Comment: @bereal Thanks for updating and explaining. But now I have one more option which is "money". I need to record the sum in each item.

So the data would look like this:
`('John', '5', 'Coke','50')
('Mary', '1', 'Pie','80')
('Jack', '3', 'Milk',45')
('Mary', '2', 'Water','10') 
('John', '3', 'Coke','30)`

And showing like this:
`John: 8 Coke, $80 
 Mary: 1 Pie , $80
 Mary: 2 Water, $10 
 Jack: 3 Milk, $45`

How could I change the `count`?
Thanks.

Comment: @WenT now it's getting more complicated and is worth a separate question. In the simplest form as it's now, that could be just two separate counters. If you have much data and more fields to aggregate, consider in-memory [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) table or a pandas dataframe with a groupby operation on them.

Comment: @bereal Thanks. I'll try to solve it by myself these days. :)

Answer (score 2):

Re-arranging the order of your data might help:

```
John: 8 Coke 
Mary: 1 Pie 
Mary: 2 Water 
Jack: 3 Milk
```

might be more insightful, when written as

```
(John, Coke) : 8
(Mary, Pie)  : 1
(Mary, Water): 2
(Jack, Milk) : 3
```

If you know SQL, this is more or less equivalent to `groupby(name, dish)` together with `sum(count)`.

So, in Python, you can create a dictionary for that pair:

```
data = [
  ('John', '5', 'Coke'),
  ('Mary', '1', 'Pie'),
  ('Jack', '3', 'Milk'),
  ('Mary', '2', 'Water'), 
  ('John', '3', 'Coke'),
]

orders = {}
for name, count, dish in data:
    if (name, dish) in orders:
        orders[(name, dish)] += int(count)
    else:
        # first entry
        orders[(name, dish)] = int(count)
```

Even more pythonic, use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
orders = defaultdict(int)
for name, count, dish in data:
    orders[(name, dish)] += int(count)
```

or `collections.Counter` as noted by @bereal.

Format data as you like.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a list of tuples

```
tuples = [('John', '5', 'Coke'),
('Mary', '1', 'Pie'),
('Jack', '3', 'Milk'),
('Mary', '2', 'Water'), 
('John', '3', 'Coke')]

memory = {}

# First, we calculate the amount for each pair
for tuple in tuples:

    # I define a generated key through the names. For example John-Cake, Mary-Pie, Jack-Milk,...
    key = (tuple[0],tuple[2])

    number = int(tuple[1])
    if key in memory:
        memory[key] += number
    else:
        memory[key] = number

# After, we format the information
list = []
for key in memory:
    list.append((key[0],memory[key],key[1]))
```

Comment: Tuples are hashtable, i.e. `('John', 'Coke')` is a valid dictionary key. No need for the string magic.